# What is this giant robot anime?

Tags: getter-robo

Bugging me for years. I saw an anime in the early 80's (I assume it was from around then, since I watched it on a VHS tape) that featured a war between a group of pilots, maybe 3 or 4, that could join into 1 giant robot. This robot had a red head with red spikes kind of like the Statue of Liberty. The bad guys had giant robots that could join together too to form 1 giant super robot, and there were maybe 6 of them.

I think it was feature length but possibly several episodes of a series put together. Also it seemed to me to not be childish. It wasn't adult but PG-ish. I recall it being sort of dark and sinister and violent. Please help me. Oh, and it wasn't Voltron or anything obvious like that.

Answer (score 2):

[image] [image] [image]

You're probably looking for **Getter Robo G**. There's several TV series and movies based on this iteration of Getter. The movies are all cross-overs with other Go Nagai mecha franchises.

- [Getter Robo G](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1993)
- [Great Mazinger tai Getter Robo G - Kuuchuu Dai-Gekitotsu](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3608)
- [Grendizer - Getter Robo G - Great Mazinger Kessen! Daikaijuu](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3616)

All from the 70's.